# How do you use LibUsbDotNet to communicate with an RTL2832U device?

Tags: c#, usb, libusbdotnet

Has anyone worked with RTL2832U (SDR) via LibUsbDotNet?

I can get details of the USB device with LibUsbDotNet but how would I go about specifically the RTL2832U as an SDR device?

I am trying to write my own SDR software in C#.

Comment: You have to look for a library for that device (if exists) and if not, you have to check `datasheet` of that exact device and program it yourself based on specifications from that datasheet.

Comment: Also check out the original implementation: https://github.com/osmocom/rtl-sdr